# Is there anyway to solve this Xcode problem?

Tags: flutter

```
Launching lib/HH-Membership/membership.dart on iPhone 15 Pro Max in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                            4.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/auth-8.2.0+02/lib/src/auth.dart:481:44: Error: The argument type 'bool?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.

Comment: Can you share which auth lib you using ? seems like that lib version is not latest one and that error is from null safety.